# how to implement sms getway api without going to other website

Tags: php, api, sms

i am using this api

http://bhashsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=success&pass=123456&sender=TESTTO&phone=$mob&text=Hi You Are registered with great skm&priority=ndnd&stype=normal

but my problem is whenever i am passed phone and text matter api not working automatically.

how can i execute this api without clicking and without going to the api website.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this sounds like it could be an encoding issue. Try:

```
$url = urlencode($url);
$get = file_get_contents($url);
if($get === false){
    throw new Exception("Failed to connect to SMS API"); 
}
echo $get;
```